# Oracle show 0 for dates with no data

Tags: oracle, missing-data

I am pulling daily data for the past year. Some dates there were 0 orders and I want to show this rather than omit completely

I have a simple query like this:

```
SELECT DATE, COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY DATE
ORDER BY DATE
```

But rather than return

```
Date         Count
01-JAN-2016  5
03-JAN-2016  7
05-JAN-2016  3
```

I want to get:

```
Date         Count
01-JAN-2016  5
02-JAN-2016  0
03-JAN-2016  7
04-JAN-2016  0
05-JAN-2016  3
```

How can this be achieved in Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You need some other table containing all the dates you are interested in; you can build such a thing on the fly with something like the following.

**Setup:**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test_date (date_col) AS
  2      (SELECT TO_DATE('01012016', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3       SELECT TO_DATE('02012016', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4       SELECT TO_DATE('02012016', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5       SELECT TO_DATE('04012016', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6       SELECT TO_DATE('04012016', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  7       SELECT TO_DATE('06012016', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  8       SELECT TO_DATE('06012016', 'ddmmyyyy') FROM DUAL
  9      );

Table created.
```

**Your query:**

```
SQL> SELECT date_col2, COUNT(date_col)
  2      FROM (    SELECT TO_DATE('01012016', 'ddmmyyyy') + LEVEL -1 AS date_col2
  3                  FROM DUAL
  4            CONNECT BY TO_DATE('01012016', 'ddmmyyyy') + LEVEL -1 <= TO_DATE('10012016', 'ddmmyyyy')) dates
  5           LEFT OUTER JOIN test_date ON (date_col = date_col2)
  6  GROUP BY date_col2
  7  ORDER BY 1;

DATE_COL2 COUNT(DATE_COL)
--------- ---------------
01-GEN-16               1
02-GEN-16               2
03-GEN-16               0
04-GEN-16               2
05-GEN-16               0
06-GEN-16               2
07-GEN-16               0
08-GEN-16               0
09-GEN-16               0
10-GEN-16               0

10 rows selected.
```

This will consider dates between 01/01/2016 and 10/01/2016, using your table in outer join; you can edit it to better fit the interval you are interested in.

Comment: This is correct, except you need + level -1 to include January 1 (level starts at 1, not at 0).

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle this is most efficiently achieved for non-trivial cases with a Partition Outer Join, specifically designed for filling sparse data.

Documented here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/tdpdw_sql.htm#TDPDW00736

Your example may fall into the trivial category, but be aware of this method also for other situations.